# Get multiple post thumbnail image title or description in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Got multiple featured images in a post and need the description of all or title of all in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Function to get description

```
    /**
     * Retrieve Post Thumbnail Description.
     *
     * @param string $post_type The post type.
     * @param string $id The id used to register the thumbnail.
     * @param int $post_id Post ID.
     * @return string
     */

    public static function the_post_thumbnail_description($post_type, $id, $post_id) {
        $post_id = (NULL === $post_id) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id;
        $postThumbnailID = get_post_meta($post_id, "{$post_type}_{$id}_thumbnail_id", true);
        $description = get_post($postThumbnailID)->post_content;
        echo $description;
    }
```

Below is the statement to call this function

```
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail_description(get_post_type(), 'feature-image-'.$i.'', Null).'<br>';
```